# Slow network time to pass large data from resolver to client

Tags: performance, graphql, apollo

I am using Apollo and GraphQL, and I have a performance issue passing he data from the resolver to the client. The response time grows in proportion to the size of the data sent. I'm trying to send about 1k nested records, and it takes somewhere in the area of 5-10 seconds depending on the result set. When sending the same data as a stringified JSON, the result takes a fraction of a second to reach the client.

I tried to increase node memory, but there was no improvement.

Relevant versions / specs:

```
"apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.5.1",
"apollo-client": "^2.5.1",
"apollo-link": "^1.2.11",
"apollo-link-error": "^1.1.10",
"apollo-link-http": "^1.5.14",
"apollo-server": "^2.4.8",
"graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
"graphql-type-json": "^0.2.4",
"graphql-yoga": "^1.17.4",
```

How can I reduce the response time from resolver to client?

Comment: Not perfectly clear what you're refering to - client (normalization in cache) or server (resolvers) ... provide some data samples, type structures, resolvers ... probably you can resolve nested data on parent level (w/o using resolvers for nested types)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I meant server side resolvers.